# Is the verb suffix -en (as in light->lighten) rooted in German?

Tags: suffixes, german

Is the verb suffix -en (as in light->lighten) rooted in German? German verbs in their infinitive form always end in -en.

Comment: German verbs in their infinitive form end in -en, -ern, or -eln.

Answer (score 1):

The English *-en* verb suffix is Germanic, but it's not related to the German infinitive ending *-en.*

English used to have an infinitive ending *-en* (as in German) which came after the suffix that you are talking about: the OED mentions Middle English forms such as "lyȝtnyn, lyghtenyn" that show two Ns.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is from **Proto-Germanic suffix  *-inojan*** and Old English *-nian*:

***[Lighten:](https://www.etymonline.com/word/lighten)***

> to make less heavy, to lighten a load," mid-14c., lighten, lightnen, from light (adj.1) + -en.

***[-en](https://www.etymonline.com/word/-en?ref=etymonline_crossreference#etymonline_v_32445)***

> word-forming element making verbs (such as darken, weaken) from adjectives or nouns, from Old English -nian, **from Proto-Germanic *-inojan*** (also source of Old Norse -na), from PIE adjectival suffix *-no-. Most active in Middle English and early modern English, hence most verbs in -en are comparatively recent.

(Etymonlyne)

Comment: And "darken", "shorten", "lengthen" etc

Comment: Interesting with colors: _redden, blacken, whiten_, but not *_bluen_, *_greenen_, *_purplen_. Also available as a prefix: _embody, enable, enjoy, enhance,_ and optionally as both: _embolden, enlighten_.

Comment: @JohnLawler It is interesting how it works with some words and not others e.g. *frighten*, *smarten*, *heighten*, but not with *calmen*. *loweren*, etc. It is interesting that in many of those that do not take the *...en* ending the noun or adjective also serves as a verb e.g. *to calm*, *to lower*.

Comment: Right. The {-en-} morpheme is no longer productive, and many of its functions have been ceded to the more usual Zero affix.